# Stack Exchange Global Flag Summary

Tags: script, flags

This is a userscript that provides a networkwide flag summary for all Stack Exchange sites.

If you are logged into the Stack Exchange network and you have this script installed, you can visit the [*flags* tab in your Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flags):

[image: SEGFS screenshot]

### How does it work?

The script scans [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) for all Stack Exchange accounts you created. For each account it tries to access the flag summary page. Since that page is private, i.e. only visible to you (and mods), you need be logged in. From there it extracts the flag summary of the individual site and sums it all up in a generated table.

The table can be sorted ascending & descending by clicking on the desired column label.

You can find a link to the global flag summary on each per-site flag summary page.

### Install

[Install from Github](https://github.com/Floern/stackoverflow/blob/master/userscripts/SE_global_flag_summary.user.js?raw=true)

[View source on Github](https://github.com/Floern/stackoverflow/blob/master/userscripts/SE_global_flag_summary.user.js)

<sup>Tested with Greasemonkey & Tampermonkey on Firefox</sup>

### Changelog

**v1.1**   Request rate and error handling improvements.

**v1.0**   Including all Meta sites; Greasemonkey 4.0 support.

**v0.8**   Fixed Area51 URL; Added site count with progress; Improved sorting.

**v0.7**   Fixed meta sites and HTTPS links; Enumerated table rows.

**v0.6**   Changed helpful % formula to `helpful / (helpful + declined) * 100`; Support for meta sites (limited) and Area 51.

**v0.5**   Initial release.

Comment: There's another use case for this script. The retrieval of the flag summary counts as a site visit for the Enthousiast & Fanatic badges. You just have to visit the global flag summary once a day.

Comment: At the moment, the script uses the site specific "last flag date", this works fine with the english sites, but it looks weird mixed with the other language stack overflow sites

Comment: You also missed the "Aged away" flag status

Comment: @Ferrybig now it should be english everywhere. The "aged away" is supposed to be the "expired" column, or doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Confirmed the all english working after script update, didn't see the expired column because I was looking for "aged away" as that's the name SE uses in the normal flag screen

Comment: This doesn't work for sites in private beta, BTW.

Comment: @Mithrandir Found the issue: The site is not listed in the [account list](//stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts), because it's a private beta..

Comment: Huh, now it's counting the private beta site.

Comment: @Mithrandir noticed that too. Not sure what's going on, maybe it was just caching..

Comment: The Area 51 link still links to discuss.area51, instead of area51.meta, just FYI.

Comment: I flagged a comment on a post where I can [previously flagged some comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEYym.png). The flag summary script then showed my last flag as being from when I flagged those comments last time - [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBRj4.png). Not sure how easy this'll be to fix, or if it's even worth any time but thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Can we discount the comment flags from the global flags summary?

Comment: @NVZ why would you want that? comment flags are flags too.

Comment: Floern, any chance this is going to the Chrome Web Store, so I don't have to follow all those instructions on installing an extension outside of the Chrome Web Store? Or can you give a crx instead of a js pretty please? Might be asking wrong questions. Anything helpful would be appreciated.

Comment: @BCLC I don't think this would make sense. If you didn't work with userscripts before, just install the Tampermonkey extension from the Chrome Web Store, and then click the "Install from Github" link above.

Comment: This script is especially useful during Winter Bash 2020, as it [can be used to instantly earn the Social Distancing hat on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358282/377214).

Comment: @Floern This script seems to show the loading GIF only and not visiting any site. When I did a little debugging, the [URL for network accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) is getting redirected to [this page](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Floern Seems like either this script has stopped working or there is some issue with Tampermonkey. Browser: Chrome.

Comment: This script does work with TamperMonkey and the Kiwi Browser (Chrome compatible) on Android. The only problems are halfway through your sites the numeric progress counter at the bottom of the page *spins* and there seems to be no progress (but occasionally a new site is added) and then about 3/4 through (all sites) it discovers that it's [being rate limited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9zgL.png); though that went away 10 minutes later.

Comment: Script works correctly, without any [rate limiting](https://stackapps.com/questions/7173/stack-exchange-global-flag-summary#comment18629_7173) problems.

Comment: Fails on iPhone with Userscripts app with this message: **Failed to load //stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts with status 0** Ideas?