# Stack Exchange Global Review Summary

Tags: script, review

## Global Review Summary

This script adds a 'reviews' tab to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), which will show your review totals across the network.

[image]

### Installation

- Install the userscript with
  [this direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/global-review-summary/global-review-summary.user.js) or get the source [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/global-review-summary/global-review-summary.user.js).

<sub>developed & tested with Violentmonkey on Firefox</sub>

### Attribution

The code of this userscript leans heavily on the
[Stack Exchange Global Flag Summary](https://stackapps.com/q/7173/34061) script by Floern.

Comment: Great userscript! But is there anyway to speed up the loading times? I'm possibly on an extremely slow network, but it took nearly 2 mins to load all my review actions across eight sites (the bottom counter was counting from `0/75` to `75/75`)

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, you need patience with this script, because it's easy to get rate-limited. It needs 6/7 calls *per site* to get the numbers, that's why there is a `let delay = 1000;` built in on line 292. Your Monkey will allow you to edit scripts locally; you could try to change it to a lower value.

Comment: Okay. Though, what is "rate-limiting"? Is it that the SE API only allows a certain number of calls per second?

Comment: @GaurangTandon in this case, the number of requests you can do in short time to the 'main' sites. CloudFlare will block you if you do more. This script doesn't use the SE API at all.

Comment: Would checking the users rep make it quicker so it does not need to check First questions, answers, posts, late answers, triage, LQP and helper if they would of never had enough rep to review them?

Comment: @Ethan good suggestion, but the situation is more complicated that it looks. Through bounties, users may have lost the review queue privilege, and during private and public betas, the privilege level may be different now than it was.

Comment: @Glorfindel Forgot about bounties. Is there a way with only 1 API request to get to the point where the user's rep was the highest? if so you can check it against the rep amounts needed in the private beta.

Comment: @Ethan not that I know of, no ...

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Add the "reviews" tab to network profiles of other users as well.

If this userscript works on my profile, can't it also work on the profile of other users? It'd be useful to see how my contribution compares to that of other users.

Comment: This is going to be tough. I take the numbers from the stats pages: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats; I know there is a [public review history for other users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2675672/gaurang-tandon?tab=activity&sort=reviews) but it's a bunch of pages,  there's no summary.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think it's doable though. Consider this related issue: [Count of different actions on suggested edits](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/307572) rene has used a script to count those actions (Edit/Improve/etc.) on suggested edits. Can it be useful for you?

Comment: Thanks. But it's going to take a while to navigate to all single pages in a user's review history, let alone for *all* sites network-wide. And I was missing something important: reviews on deleted posts don't show up in there, but they *do* count for the review stats.

Comment: @Glorfindel "reviews on deleted posts don't show up in there" Oh, well that's totally a show-stopper, considering that many LQP reviews, etc. end up being deleted :( Anyway, I hope you'll keep thinking about this for a while, and try come up with something, maybe there's another way? :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using the SEDE route but I'm not sure if the reviewers identity are kept in the database.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I am not sure why it has suddenly stopped working. It doesn't collect any data but it seems to visit the sites. There are no stats displayed. Just blank.

**Browser:** Firefox.

**Add-on:** Tampermonkey.

Comment: It seems Stack Exchange is making some changes to the review pages, causing the script to break. I'll have a look after my vacation.

Comment: @Glorfindel OK. Not an issue. Enjoy your vacation.

Comment: It's working again in version 0.4. Thank you for reporting this!

Comment: @Glorfindel The issue is back.

Comment: I see, I'll have a look later this week. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I haven't changed anything, but it's working again (at least for me).

Comment: @Glorfindel The OS doesn't have to do anything with it, does it?